# Wordpress submit button not showing in Dolphin

Tags: forms, wordpress, plugins, contacts

I created a form for a Wordpress theme, using Easy Contact Form' plugin which works fine for conventional browsers but on Android's Dolphin browser, the 'Submit' button is not showing up.

Is there a reason for this, are there other form plugins that would work with both desktop and mobile browsers?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was using Wordpress EZ Contact Form which didn't work so I switched to the Contact Form 7 plugin. The submit now shows on Android.